# What is NameServerAddressList in the OPS page?

Tags: dashboard, rocketmq

I have setup the rocketmq Dashboard and I was exploring it.
What exactly is the NameServerAddressList?. It is somehow defaulted to 127.0.0.1:9876.

[image]

Also, The dashboard looks empty, How do I monitor RocketMQ clusters.
Do I need to create clusters, topics, producers, consumers on my own or can I monitor something which is already pre-built.

[image]

PS: I'm a newbie contributor :) and I hope these questions are not stupid.